# Auto Indent in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I paste some code into VSCode from somewhere else, I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj8fr.png)

Is there a shortcut to format createNode to the same format and indentation as main()? I'm only used to intelliJ which does it with Ctrl + K but I don't know how to do it here and searching didn't yield any meaningful results either. Thank you!

Comment: On Windows by default ALT+SHIFT+F is the hotkey to reformat the code. But I'm not sure, if it changes the createNode indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Enable this setting:

> Editor: Format On Paste

Otherwise select it all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will format the selection.

Or as @tenkmillan says <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> formats the whole document.

But the `Format On Paste` setting is what you are specifically looking for.